# Woo Related Products How to override the plugin script?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

1. Plugin Woo Related Products
2. Directory: `wp-content\plugins\woo-related-products-refresh-on-reload`
3. Need override js file: `wp-content\plugins\woo-related-products-refresh-on-reload\public\js\woo-related-products-public.js`
4. Js include in file: `wp-content\plugins\woo-related-products-refresh-on-reload\public\class-woo-related-products-public.php`

Code:

```
if (esc_attr(get_option('woorelated_slider')) == 'Enabled') {
        wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/woo-related-products-public.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );
```

5. Copy js file to: `wp-content/themes/child-storefront-theme/woo-related-products-refresh-on-reload/js/woo-related-products-public.js`
6. Add code to `functions.php`

   `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_woo_related_products');
   function custom_woo_related_products()
   {
       wp_dequeue_script('woo-related-products');
       wp_enqueue_script('woo-related-products', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/woo-related-products-refresh-on-reload/js/woo-related-products-public.js', array('jquery'));
   }`

   But it does not work. Where is the mistake?

Comment: when you use the priorty "100", are you sure that the call with this priority is after the call of the plugin Woo Related Products ?

Comment: Not sure. I set other values. No changes

Comment: to know that, you have to find on which hook is called `wp_enqueue_script` in the original script. and display the value of `$this->plugin_name` to be sure to have the good name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy js file to: `wp-content/themes/child-storefront-theme/assets/js/woo-related-products-refresh-on-reload/woo-related-products-public.js`

```
function custom_woo_related_products() {
    wp_dequeue_script('woo-related-products');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-woo-related-products', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/woo-related-products-refresh-on-reload/woo-related-products-public.js', array('jquery'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_woo_related_products', 100);
```

Why 100? To be dequeued, the script must have been enqueued. Attempting to dequeue a script before the script is enqueued will have no effect.